# passing event to function outside of class in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

What do I have to do to handle an event with a function located outside of the class the event is triggered from.  For example, the code below works fine when the onClick method is called when the panel is clicked.

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Cubit 2D',size=(600,600))
        self.Center()
        self.panel=(wx.Panel(self))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('grey')

        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.onClick)

    def onClick(self,event):
        print 'hello'
```

However, if I move the function onClick to a different .py file like shown below, it doesn't work.  How do I pass the event info to the function located in the other file?

```
#main file

import wx
import onclick

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Cubit 2D',size=(600,600))
        self.Center()
        self.panel=(wx.Panel(self))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('grey')

        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,onclick.onClick)
```

other file with function

```
def onClick(self,event):
    print 'hello'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `self` parameter from the `onClick` function in the other file:

```
def onClick(event):
    print 'hello'
```

You only need the `self` parameter for instance methods, not ordinary functions.

Comment: tried that.  This is the error I get. AttributeError: 'MyFrame' object has no attribute 'event'